# Firebase storage authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-web

I want to restrict access to Firebase Storage objects with storage rules and custom claims on authenticated users. Both cool features, good for scaling.

My problem however is:

The Firebase Storage download link allows public access, no matter the rules.

My download link given by getDownloadURL() is:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/***myappname***.appspot.com/o/logos%2F1618740110634.png?alt=media&token=bdf6a5c5-54a2-4211-aa40-85177a38210a

My rules are:

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if false;
}
```

What link then should I use to restrict access to authenticated users only and for checking custom claims with for my admin (excel reports) files? I am very confused.

Have tried direct links, without the token at the end, the given storage location link.
With the public link, anyone has access I don't want them to have.

Using Flutter mobile and web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getDownloadURL()` always returns a public URL. Everyone who has it can access the file.

There are short lived `signed` token URLs but they are not supported on native device SDKs.

The `downloadURL` is very secure. If someon does not have it no one will get to your file. So the magic here is to not share it anywere and to get what you would like work only with references. Only if someone has access to your reference (according to the storage rules) he can generate the `downloadURL`.

I would recommend to work in your app only with those references and only get the `downloadURL` when you realy want to access the file in App or open it.

In the firebase storage rules you can then use `auth` and the `customClaims` to define who can access the file references.

Once a `downloadURL` is generated the firebase storage rules don't matter. The file will be accessible over that link.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the whole setup for me. It makes much more sense. I understand that the rules are for when the download url is being requested. Thanks a lot!